# class swapping with angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, css

I am opening and closing some side (open and close under the title) using angular and I'm wondering if there is a way I can swap between classes When I'm doing this too so I can swap some css. Here's what I'm doing -

```
<form name="metaDeta" id="lessonDetails" class="lessonItem" ng-controller="detailsController">
    <div class="small-12 columns">
    <div class="lesonHead lessonHeadOpen saDetailsHead" ng-click="showDetails = ! showDetails"  ng-class="myVar">

            <h5>Lesson Details</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="lessonSASlider" ng-show="showDetails">
```

This works fine for opening and closing the form, however there is a class .lessonHeadOpen that I would like to try and toggle between .lessonHeadClosed. So basically I am looking for something like an addClass/removeClass even on click to toggle between the 2 classes on the element when the user opens and closes it. Is this possible with angular? Could I work off what I have or do I have to re-structure. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ng-class to dynamically add classes based on the result of expressions. 
[**Read ngClass**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass)

```
<div class="lessonHead" ng-click="showDetails = ! showDetails">
  <h5>Lesson Details</h5>
</div>
<div ng-class="{className: showDetails}">
</div>
```

This directive will evaluate showDetails expression and if true, it will apply the class `className`

**Update:**
If I understand correctly, do the same but reverse the expression so if not showdetails add one class and then when show details is true it will be removed and the other class added. `<div ng-class="{classOne: showDetails , classTwo: !showDetails}">` 
[**SEE FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/cpd13mkp/)

Comment: This is awesome, however I am looking to try and toggle between classes. So could it pull off the old class and replace. I am looking for something to the effect of removeClass('oldClass') and addClass('newClass') in jquery to get the effect of toggling between them So I can swap an image along with some other stuff with different css classes. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ng-class](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) for toggling.
Simply add a condition for a class to appear and it will based on the condition.

```
ng-class="{'className': shouldShowClass}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng-class`'s ternary operator notation:

```
<div ng-class="showDetails? 'lessonHeadOpen': 'lessonHeadClosed'>...</div>
```

**[SAMPLE DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/zql80GPS5FswDLexXiB0?p=preview)**